# How does one report a bug in Stack Overflow HTML?

Tags: support, bug-reports

The following is about how to report bugs. It is not a bug report.

Should bugs in the HTML code of pages served from Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange sites be reported here on meta.stackexchange.com?  (The FAQ implies it is OK to report bugs here, but doesn't explicitly say whether bugs are supposed to be reported here or somewhere else.)

If MSO is appropriate venue, what question-tags should be used for bug reports?
For example, if the bug concerns comments displaying properly on math.stackexchange.com and on english.stackexchange.com but improperly (with text overwriting causing illegibility) on stackoverflow.com and meta.stackoverflow.com, what tags would be appropriate?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Questions about Stack Exchange sites, or the engine they use are on-topic here. Reporting here bugs that are not related to software used to run Stack Exchange sites is not on-topic, though.

For a bug report, the first tag you should add is [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), followed by a tag that is specific for the bug being reported, such as [theme](/questions/tagged/theme), or [design](/questions/tagged/design); both the tags could suit for bug reports about the HTML used to render pages on a Stack Exchange site. Another tag you could use in the case you have described could be [css](/questions/tagged/css); as then you speak of how comments are rendered, then [comments](/questions/tagged/comments) is the other tag you could use.

Comment: [meta-tag:design] is a good one to use as then it will be seen by the designer (Jin).