# Bug on the questions/ask pages of SE

Tags: bug, design

As far as I can tell this hasn't been reported yet.

**BUG**: The "How to Format", and "Similar Questions" widgets (?) seem to be overlapping the footer when you scroll to the bottom.  Pictures attached.  This happens on the questions/ask pages on SE.

I have confirmed it on meta, SO, and Programmers.  On both Edge 25 and Chrome 48, on both a laptop with a 1366x768 and a computer with a 1080 display.

[image: Snap 1]

[image: Snap 2]

[Reporting Procedures Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111070/how-does-one-report-a-bug-in-stack-overflow-html)

Comment: Sorry guys.  I definitely did not use the word: Sidebar when I was searching - and that was the word I was looking for.  My apologies.

Comment: No harm done. This bug is so obvious and glaring that many people report it, each with different wording. :)