# Down vote changed to up vote caused reputation meter to pass daily maximum

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, reputation-display

I just experienced a minor visual bug.

I had an answer that earned 2 down votes and 22+ upvotes, earning me the daily maximum of +200. Upon making some edits to the answer at the behest of the comments, one of the users who down voted changed their vote. Now my reputation meter shows that I gained +202 for the day.

[image: Over the reputation cap for the day]

This correctly did *NOT* affect my reputation, as I still only gained 200, so it is merely a minor display bug.

This appears in the achievements drop down and my reputation tab on my profile.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: It will fix itself whenever your account gets recalculated again.

Comment: @Ramhound It's a bug report. No question. See "How does one report a bug in stack overflow" http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111070/how-does-one-report-a-bug-in-stack-overflow-html which says, essentially, "Post a question tagged as bug", which is what I did.

Comment: If there's another way to report a bug, I'll gladly do that. Also, @animuson, I don't care if it "fixes itself", I don't even care if it continues to show +202. All I care about is that bugs are reported to be evaluated by the product owners. It's their decision whether it's too minor to fix, not mine. If I didn't report it, I'd be making that decision, which again, is not my choice to make, it's theirs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just the way the system is built to work. The only way to "fix" this is to have an account be recalculated every time someone retracts a vote to make sure it doesn't break the user's cap. That's incredibly resource-intensive and not a viable option. So the alternative is to just go ahead and process it anyways and wait for the system to correct it on its own later. Whenever your account gets scheduled for recalculation in the future, the oddity will disappear.