# Tooltip of "Show activity on this post"-link doesn't line up with others

Tags: bug, design, tooltips

I noticed a little (very minor) flaw when hovering over the left-hand side buttons for *up-/downvote*, *bookmark* and *activity* found next to every question and answer.

### The Problem

The popover-tooltips of these buttons all vertically line up just fine - except for the last one. The "button" for "Show activity on this post" has a smaller width, resulting in the tooltip being displayed closer to this one "button" than the other ones.

[image]

Or, alternatively, a direct comparison between the tooltips and the one above it in one picture:

[image]

This is a very minor visual design flaw, but it's noticeable. I tested this in current versions of Firefox and Chromium.

### Reason

In the above paragraph, I put "button" in quotation marks, because the "button" for *"Show activity on this post"* actually is an anchor (`a`) and not a button (`button`) like the other ones. This is semantically correct use of HTML, as a button should trigger some action on the loaded page and an anchor should instead "navigate" somewhere (another page or area of a page). But as a result, the width of this element (the anchor) differs from the width of the buttons above. It's tooltip is therefor out of line with the other ones.

### Possible solution

Adding the CSS property `width: 100%;` to the anchor (`<a class="js-post-issue grid--cell s-btn`...) solves this, but I am not sure whether specifying `width` for an anchor is good style. Maybe there's a better solution.

PS: I hope this way of reporting such things is okay, I relied on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111070/how-does-one-report-a-bug-in-stack-overflow-html?newreg=001661c9b8034152a917441b2424fc61) question from 8 years ago.

Comment: The gif moves too fast, it's impossible to see the problem. Please post still screenshots instead.

Comment: I think it's hard to see the difference on still screenshots, so i made another, slower, more to-the-point GIF.

Comment: I pushed my GIMP skills to the limit and also created a still image with the two tooltips displayed at once ;)

Comment: Cheers, now it's bright and clear. ;-)

Comment: It's also awful if the post has a really high score; the first four (if you have view vote totals privileges) tooltips are straight and aligned, but the last one leaps right in.

Comment: I never noticed this but now I can't unsee it :D.