# How to fix the visualization of latex equations in dark mode (SO)?

Tags: support, images, mathjax

Recently, I was reading a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530026/insertion-sort-analysis-and-summation-notation) on SO including LaTex equations, and it happens that in dark mode the visualization of the math is not well implemented...
A quick solution would be to change the background color to white (or grey, some eyes may be grateful) in order to improve the contrast with the letters (the equations are images with transparent backgrounds).
I Would like to know how can I help to improve this feature, or if this is currently being developed because I think it's important for the widespread of the dark theme on all the Stack Exchange sites related to math.
[I hope this is the right place to report this...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/111071/743698)
[image: example of how I'm seeing the equations in SO with dark theme]

Comment: [Related on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405271/7296893). Stack Overflow doesn't have mathjax support, these are just pictures on transparent backgrounds. Ideally, if the picture required a white background to be legible, the author of that picture would not make the background transparent.

Comment: I get it, so it's just a particularity of the question as @Luuklang pointed? The OP put the image rather than the equation

Comment: Yes @ego2509, SO does not support MathJax. An overview of the sites that do can be found here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax

Comment: thank you all, I'll accept the answer. There's nothing else to add here apparently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are not LaTex equations, if you look closely at the Markdown of the post you see the following for the first equation:

> I understand the first formula:
>
> ![Σ(j=1 to n) j=n(n+1)/2][2]

This markdown resembles the commonly used format for linking pictures: `![Image Description][X]` where X is a unique reference.

At the bottom of the post you see:

> `[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfy6c.gif`

Which is the address of the image that is included in the post.
It appears that this image is transparent, and hence the poor contrast is the result.

Comment: I'd guess its pre dark mode. I wonder if it makes sense to convert it to a white background or if there's a better alternative

Comment: Yes it deffinetly is @JourneymanGeek, it's from '12. Re-rendering those images to have a white background would certainly help yes, but that would most likely constitute of taking screenshots of each and every equation, and then re-uploading them. Perhaps if Glorfindel is bored he could employ his bot ;)

Comment: Oh not really. I have a trick from work that might help

Comment: .... suggested edit queue is full

Comment: yeah that's a known problem at SO @JourneymanGeek

Comment: The alternative, mentioned in the MSO post, would be to add `.js-post-body img { background-color:white; }` to the stylesheet, which would put a background color behind transparent images. I don't think it would affect images that aren't transparent.